# FileNotFoundException in Android - From disc

Tags: android

I need to read a picture from my disc, but i have FileNotFoundException !

```
try {

    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/wakaicon.png"));

} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

    Log.e("DEBUG", "[Picture Not Found]");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator is a seperated virtual machine on your pc - adb is the solution to push the file to your external sdcard or in another directory(here's the guide: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). 
You can't reach your HDD in apps. To reach files on your externeal directory try this code:

```
getExternalStorageDirectory ()
```

It returns a File. And here is the documentation about it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

EDIT:
You could push the file with adb to your external sdcard and then you could try something like

```
File env = Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
File folder = new File(env,"Pictures/yourNewPic")
if(!folder.exists()){folder.mkdirs()}
```

Requires `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission> in your manifest.`

Answer (score 0):

In android we cannot get the file from any  part of your disc. you have to create the external storage in your emulator or device and have to provide the path like "mnt/sdcard/yourfolder/yourfile.

Hope this helps you.

you can try like this also.

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
```

Comment: The path of sdcard in my disc ?

Comment: No, getExternalStoragedirectory will return a path like /mnt/sdcard0/ and in 'new File(dir, XY)' xy means the folder where you wanna put your files or create a directory on your external sd card. You can't reach your PC disk within the emulator.

Comment: you cannot load your PC disk files from your android program. its for accessing the mobiles alone. if you can create the external storage in your emulator . then insert the file in your sdcard then test it .

Comment: Thanks everbody, I have found the solution for my problem ...
1. Create SD Card (through Edit AVD)
2. Open The File Explorer (IDE -> Window -> Show View -> File Explore)
3. Add the picture to the SD CARD directory

Comment: yes...you are right.. if my answer is helped you vote it or accept it

Comment: other helpful ;) ... :
http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for my problem ... 
1. Create SD Card (through Edit AVD) 
2. Open The File Explorer (IDE -> Window -> Show View -> File Explore) 
3. Add the picture to the SD CARD directory

```
package com.example.wakauploadpicture;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class handlePicture {
    handlePicture(){}
    //
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean handlePicture(String filePath, String mimeType) {       
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outStream = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;

        String lineEnd = "-----------------------------16572156320853";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "---------------------------29463111463415";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;

        byte[] buffer;

        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

        String urlString = "http://192.168.224.37:8081/waUpload/upload/uploadHandlers.js";
        Log.v("State : ",Environment.getExternalStorageState());
        Log.v("",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath(), "wakaicon.png");
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
            try {               
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {              
                Log.e("DEBUG", "[Picture Not Found]");
            }
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //indicates that the application intends to read data from the URL connection. 
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            //indicates that the application intends to write data to the URL connection. 
            connection.setDoOutput(true);           
            connection.setUseCaches(true);

            //Set the method for the URL request, one of: POST
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.waPage/index.html");

            //connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+file.length());
            Log.v("Content-Length", ""+file.length());
            outStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            outStream.writeBytes(boundary);
            outStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filesToUpload\"; filename=\"" + "wakaicon.png");
            outStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: "+ mimeType);
//        
//          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
//          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
//          buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
//
//          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
//
//            while (bytesRead > 0) {
//                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
//                Log.v("Buffer : ",buffer.toString());
//              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
//              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
//              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
//              outStream.write(bytesRead);
//          }

            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100 , baos);    
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            Log.v("byte : ",""+b[i]);
            outStream.write(b[i]);
            }


            outStream.write(getBytesFromBitmap(bm));                
              outStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens+boundary);
              outStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"config\"");
              outStream.writeBytes("{\"folder\":\"tmp\",\"replace\":false,\"datasource\":{\"dsname\":\"Emloyee\",\"id\":\"5\",\"field\":\"photo\",\"saveOnDS\":true}}");
              outStream.writeBytes(boundary+twoHyphens);
            fileInputStream.close();
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();  
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "[MalformedURLException while sending a picture]");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "[IOException while sending a picture]"); 
        }

        try {
               String sHeaderValue = connection.getResponseMessage();
               Log.v("Response : ",sHeaderValue);
               inStream = new DataInputStream( connection.getInputStream() );
               String str;

               while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                   Log.v("str pic :",str);
                   if(str=="1") {
                       return true;
                   } else {
                       return false;
                   }
               }
               inStream.close();        
          } catch (IOException e){
              Log.e(e.toString(), "[IOException while sending a picture and receiving the response]");
          }
        return false;

    }


    public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```